# Partial Fraction, numerator with a higher degree

Tags: definite-integrals, partial-fractions

I've been posed with the following question:

$\int^3_1(x^2\div (2x+1)) dx$

I was able to determine via long division that:

$x^2\div (2x+1)$ = $\frac12x-(\frac12x\div(2x+1))$

however, I can't determine how to get past this point, could anyone help? Working would be appreciated.

Sorry for the bad formatting, I can't figure out how to use the fraction  function properly.

Comment: It's `\frac{x^2}{2x+1}`. For a more elaborate list of MatJax command you might want to look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You didn't finish your long division.

Comment: @KittyL ahh I see, I didn't even notice I could go further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Long division should have given you:
$$\frac{x^2}{2x+1}=\frac x2-\frac14+\frac1{4(2x+1)}.$$